# Can Jewish knights have more than one wife?

Tags: pendragon

Since Knights & Ladies, you can have a Jewish knight in Pendragon. The thing is, the prohibition against polygamy for Ashkenazi Jews wasn't until around 1000 CE, and while it was considered unwise by some, it was completely allowed for the average jew. What I'm not so sure about it how it applies to a Jewish *knight*, hence the question.

(From a game perspective, I can see how it might be unfairly advantageous, since wives come with dowries and extra manors, but since Pendragon as a game is so hung up on historical/mythological accuracy...)

Comment: What makes you think that a Jew would even have been allowed to become a knight?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Besides that the fact that the sourcebook specifically says that and gives rules for their creation, you mean? It lists sources where there were Jewish knights in Arthurian myth, but unfortunately I don't own the book, a friend of mine does.

Comment: This actually sounds like a question that might actually get a better answer on https://history.stackexchange.com

Comment: @divibisan It wouldn't really apply there as, like Jeff said, Jewish knights didn't really exist in actual history. Also, I'd prefer an answer based on a Pendragon sourcebook, if possible.

Comment: Since you're asking about a historical prohibition, if you can separate it from the game milieu, you might be able to get a better answer from [judaism.se] than from here.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin well Palamedes as a Saracen counts - though he was a convert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Knights and Ladies section includes extra lands you can be from. If you come from a land where polygamy is allowed, you can certainly do it.

The person who is likely to forbid you is your Lord. If your acts are public enough, it may come to the attention of your king.

> Knights are sheriff, judge, and jury for all matters of Low Justice on
>   their own domains (see below  for the three types of temporal
>   justice). If a character  has land, then it is his responsibility to
>   maintain justice within it. Likewise, on their lord’s land, knights
>   must act on their lord’s behalf, either delivering justice then and
>   there or else taking the wrongdoer to the lord’s court. Knights who
>   break the law are subject to justice in the courts of whoever was
>   offended. If the law breaking takes place in a knight’s own domain,
>   then  his own lord makes judgment. The only exception  to this is when
>   a knight breaks a rule of his lord, in  which case the other knights
>   of the court stand to  deliver a judgment.  Appeal to a higher court
>   can be made, but the  higher lord’s court can always decide whether or
>   not to  hear the petition.  Knights accused of wrongdoing at any time
>   may  claim trial by combat instead of normal court justice. (p22 core)

If you have the social pull and influence to get multiple people to marry you and your lord disagrees, you can also demand trial by combat to say you are innocent. If your lord (and eventually king) is fine with it, your word is law of the land, and you can decide whether polygamy should be legal. It's expected that you'll have lovers and concubines of course

> Many children are born out of wedlock. Noblemen  seem especially
>   subject to propagating this vice. Their partners are sometimes called
>   lovers, concubines, courtesans, or  paramours, and are frequently of a
>   social class significantly  lower than that of the nobleman. (p21 core)

If you are willing to forgo the manorhouse, it's a lot easier. As the book notes, taking concubines is common. So long as they're of a lower class they're not a threat to your political union, so it's more permissible.

http://www.academia.edu/3618260/Concubinage_and_polygyny_in_the_Middle_Ages_Lets_talk_about_sex_

And historically, polygyny was common, if detested by the church. The first wife may have some legal recourse if you try to take a second wife.

> As the aforementioned paragraph 23 of the Cáin Lánamna suggests, the
>   cétmuinter was entitled to the coibche her husband gave to a new wife,
>   the adaltrach .Furthermore, a gloss to Heptad 6 allowed the cétmuinter
>   to inflict any non-fatal injury on her husband’s second wife for a
>   period of three days, while the adaltrach was only allowed to scratch,
>   pull hair, speak abusively or inflict minor injuries in retaliation.

You should definitely discuss these matters with your DM. Under the law, your first wife may well be able to 'accidentally' kill your second wife, and have you pay compensation.

p204 also has a table for any cuckolds. Your wife may decide to roll on that table and get vengeance on you, per the above historical notes.